# Looking for QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS "Adaptive Smoothing" tool

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, buffer

I am trying to find a tool that is similar to "Adaptive Smoothing" (found on ArcGIS) on QGIS. What I am trying to do is eliminate narrow drainages (narrow corridors less than 6 m wide). This is part of my predictive wetland model.

I have tried getting the negative buffer of the polygons (i.e. 6 m) and then I got the positive buffer (6 m). I found that this eliminated the narrow drainages but when I created the polygons, the buffered result didn't maintain the shape of the original polygon.

Is there a way to maintain the shape of a buffered polygon?

This is the before result (note narrow fingers):

[image]

Here is the result of de-buffering and buffering. This is almost what I want but I want the buffered result to maintain the shape of the original polygons (minus the narrow fingers):

[image]

Is there a way to achieve what I have done but somehow maintain the polygon boundary which was found in the original polygons?

Comment: For those without access to ArcGIS: can you explain what Adaptive Smoothing does? Can you show us on your picture what you want to eliminate - maybe a preview how the result should look like?

Comment: Thanks. I updated my comments. Since the original comment, I found some ways to get one step closer to the product I want. The main thing I am trying to determine now is how to maintain the polygon shape of the buffered item.

Comment: Does the intersection of the buffered polygons with the original polygons give you the result you want?

Comment: I would habe had the same idea as @Jake. Erioderma, can you provide sample data for testing?

Comment: I am testing this out as we speak. What would the best way to provide sample data if I don't have success with trying the intersection tool? @Babel

Comment: No luck. Essentially I am looking for a Geodesic option which is found on Arc:                    https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/tool-reference/big-data-analytics/create-buffers.htm#:~:text=The%20geodesic%20method%20creates%20a%20shape-preserving%20geodesic%20buffer,closely%20represent%20the%20shape%20of%20the%20input%20features.

Comment: Load your data to a cloud and share the link here (no possibility here to upload).

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u9l3h9kd6i9osyo/AAB4btlJPs7VM3J1IyKnhjkia?dl=0                   Vector data is found here. I want to get rid of narrow fingers which are likely not wetlands but just drainages. I randomly chose the threshold to be 6 m but could be less.

Comment: To remove narrow corridors less than 6 m wide, you should use -3 m buffer, not -6.

Comment: You are correct. Good point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do a negative buffer and then a positive buffer something like 1.5 times larger than your negative buffer and then use that to clip your original layer.
[image: negative buffer]
[image: larger positive buffer]
[image: clipped layer]
It's not perfect as you lose some of your "fingers" but it works pretty well. To figure out what the ideal buffer sizes are I use a buffer in a geometry generator to play with numbers.
[image: geometry generator]

Comment: Great if you could mark it as answered that might be helpful for future users. Also perhaps the title should be changed to 'Remove Narrow Polygon Areas but Retain Shape QGIS' or something.